# react map is not a function error in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS and I am getting an error that I don't understand.  This is my first written with ReactJS app. Here is my code.

#### Error

`react map is not a function error in my app`

#### SearchBar Component

```
import RecipeList from './recipes_list';

class SearchBar extends Component {

    state = {
        term : []
    }

    onInputChange(term){
        this.setState({term});
    }

    onSubmit = async (term) => {
        const recName= this.state.term;
        term.preventDefault();
        const api_key = 'a21e46c6ab81bccebfdfa66f0c4bf5e9';
        const api_call = await Axios
          .get(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${api_key}&q=${recName}&`)
          .then(res=> {this.setState({term : res.data.recipes})})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
            <div className="search-bar">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.term}
                onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
              />
              <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <RecipeList List ={this.state.term}/>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

#### RecipeList Component

```
const RecipeList = props => (
  <div>
    {
      props.List.map((recipe) => {
        return (
          <div>{recipe.title}</div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
)
export default RecipeList;
```

Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .map function is only available on array.
It looks like data isn't in the format you are expecting it to be (it is {} but you are expecting []).

```
this.setState({data: data});
```

should be

```
this.setState({data: data.conversations});
```

Check what type "data" is being set to, and make sure that it is an array.

More generally, you can also convert the new data into an array and use something like concat:

```
var newData = this.state.data.concat([data]);  
this.setState({data: newData})
```

This pattern is actually used in Facebook's ToDo demo app (see the section "An Application") at https://facebook.github.io/react/.

Comment: Thanks, Harsh for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this snippet:

```
onInputChange(term){
 this.setState({term});
}
```

This will set your state variable to a String. For example, if I type in `Hello!`, your state object will be `{ term: 'Hello!' }`. You're now trying to `.map()` over a String, `String.map` is not a function.